# How Can I Check If Mail id Available in DB or not?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, form-validation, contact-form

I am getting so many spam from inquiry submission,

My contact form :

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Us') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php // echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('tm/googlemap/contacts_map.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tm_googlemap_contacts') ?>
<div class="contact-block clearfix">
    <div class="contact-left"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('contact_block')->toHtml() ?></div>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
        <div class="fieldset">
            <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field last">
                        <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="wide">
                    <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons-set">
            <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
            <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

How can i check if customer registered or not compared from  my customer DB, for avoiding spam submission.

Note : If not registered i need to show alert box "You are not registered, You Need to signup"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rewrite `Mage_Contacts_IndexController::postAction()`

After field validation you can add something like:

```
$customerFound = true;
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
    ->loadByEmail(trim($post['email']));

if (!$customer->getId()) {
    $customerFound = false;
    throw new Exception();
}
```

And inside the `catch` block you can change the error message like:

```
if (!$customerFound) {
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('You are not registered, You Need to signup'));
} else {
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
}
```

---

To avoid spam I'd recommend this free extension: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/HoneySpam

Comment: If i try to change in app\code\local\Mage\Contacts\controllers instead of app\code\core\Mage\Contacts\controllers its not working, may i know the reason,,, because as you know core file edit is not good, right?

Comment: @zus Its not possible for controllers ... you have to create a module and add a rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid spaming you need to add captcha to the contact form of your website.

I was facing the same problem for magento 1.9.3 but now its resolved by adding captcha to contact form, registration form and login form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can i add captcha for my contact form.

Comment: You can this captcha extension: https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html. I have used and make it work. Please follow the how to enable it from admin after install.